# relation "django_plotly_dash_statelessapp" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "django_plotly_dash_statel

Tags: python, django, deployment, render, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy my Django app on render. But there is an error which I don't understand what type of error is this.Please help to solve this

```
error: ProgrammingError at /nickelpure/[relation "django_plotly_dash_statelessapp" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "django_plotly_dash_statel...
                                      ^
```

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWfgk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to deploy migrations files and run `python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb` command.

Comment: No, it's not working

Comment: @Robert_T119 try `python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb`